# 配列がネストされているJSONファイルをCSV形式で出力したい

Tags: json, aws-cli, jq

以下の `aws-cli` の出力結果で得られたJSONファイルをcsvファイルに変換したいです。
変換はWindowsコマンドプロンプト上の `jq` で実施したく、試行錯誤したのですが思い通りの出力結果とならずアドバイスいただきたいです。

**csvに変換したいJSONファイル**

```js
[
    [
        {
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-07d6xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-00c4xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "GroupId": [
                "sg-12cfxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "sg-0063xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0334xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-0ee6xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "GroupId": [
                "sg-8c45xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

**期待するcsv出力結果**

```
"eni-07d6xxxxxxxxxxxxx","i-00c4xxxxxxxxxxxxx","sg-12cfxxxxxxxxxxxxx","sg-0063xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"eni-0334xxxxxxxxxxxxx","i-0ee6xxxxxxxxxxxxx","sg-8c45xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

#### 試したこと

以下をコマンドプロンプトで実行してcsvに出力したのですが、期待するcsv出力結果とならず添付画像のように複数行にまたがって出力されてしまいます。また、何故か列がずれて出力されてしまいます。

```
type output.json | jq.exe -r ".[] | .[] | [.NetworkInterfaceId,.InstanceId,.GroupId[0],.GroupId[1]] | @csv" > test.csv`
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 質問したいこと

・期待する出力結果のようにENI毎に一行にまとめるにはどうすればいいでしょうか。
・試したコマンドではGroupIDを配列の番号で指定しているのですが要素が2つ以上になった場合にエラーが出てしまいます。配列の要素数分をcsvに出力したいのですがいい案ありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下は map と flatten を使う方法です。

```
$ lsb_release -dr
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10

$ jq --version
jq-1.6

$ jq -r '.[]|map(.NetworkInterfaceId + .InstanceId + .GroupId)|flatten|@csv' output.json    
"eni-07d6xxxxxxxxxxxxx","i-00c4xxxxxxxxxxxxx","sg-12cfxxxxxxxxxxxxx","sg-0063xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"eni-0334xxxxxxxxxxxxx","i-0ee6xxxxxxxxxxxxx","sg-8c45xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: 返信遅くなりすみません。期待通りの結果となりました。ご回答ありがとうございます。